# MongoDb limit the update query

Tags: mongodb

I want to change the payment type Postpaid to POSTPAID and I want to limit that query, for this purpose I wrote following query:

```
db.subscribers.find({paymentType:"Postpaid"}).limit(3).forEach(
function(doc)
{db.collection.update(
{paymentType:"Postpaid"},
{$set:{paymentType:"POSTPAID"}},
db.subscribers.save(doc)
)})
```

and it gives following output but nothing changes:

```
Updated 1 existing record(s) in 3ms
Updated 0 record(s) in 1ms
Updated 1 existing record(s) in 2ms
Updated 0 record(s) in 1ms
Updated 1 existing record(s) in 2ms
Updated 0 record(s) in 1ms
```

what is wrong with that query can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do update query, just update value in `doc` and save it to same collection,

```
db.subscribers.find({paymentType:"Postpaid"}).limit(3).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.paymentType = "POSTPAID";
    db.subscribers.save(doc);
});
```

- Second option, do update query

```
db.subscribers.find({ paymentType: "Postpaid" }).limit(3).forEach(function(doc) {
    db.subscribers.updateOne(
      { _id: doc._id },
      { $set: { paymentType: "POSTPAID" } }
    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not working in my case it gives the following output for each record : The dollar ($) prefixed field '$numberLong' in 'version.$numberLong' is not valid for storage.

Comment: might be there is some $sign in some of the fields, it will not support in below 4.2 version you can try second option.

Comment: the second query worked in my case even my mongo version 4.4.2 thanks a lot